# Getting dataframe extent from a polygon and exporting to PDF issue

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, extents, pdf, data-frame

I created a script to get the extent of a polygon, apply it to the data frame extent, and then export the layout as a PDF. However, I'm not getting any errors but the script is printing out at a different scale and the wrong area (can't quite tell what area it is that it's printing/moving to).

Can anyone point me to what may be causing the issue and/or any documentation that might help me figure out what the problem is?

The script is as follows:
(Note, there are no parameters since I'm automating a very specific workflow that utilizes templates and the same layer names each time).

```
# Import modules

import arcpy
from arcpy import mapping

# Allow overwriting
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Get the X and Y information for each polygon
mxd = mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
    if lyr.name == "MapbookGrid":
        mapGrid = lyr

# Set the current data frame as a variable
dataframe = mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]

# Gets the extent of the current data frame
frameExtent = dataframe.extent

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(mapGrid)
shapeName = arcpy.Describe(mapGrid).shapeFieldName
for row in rows:
    feat = row.getValue(shapeName)
    Name = str(row.PageNumber)
    #print "Executing print of page: "+str(Name)
    arcpy.AddMessage("Executing print of page {0}".format(Name))
    extent = feat.extent
    pdfName = Name + ".pdf"
    pdfStore = r"\\GISAPPSER2\Engineering_GIS\ScriptWork" + pdfName
    #print pdfStore
    arcpy.AddMessage("PDF name is {0} and is stored as {1}".format(pdfName, pdfStore))
# Obtain X and Y
    XMAX = extent.XMax
    XMIN = extent.YMin
    YMAX = extent.YMax
    YMIN = extent.YMin
# Store data frame extent from polygon
    frameExtent.XMax, frameExtent.YMax = XMAX, YMAX
    frameExtent.XMin, frameExtent.YMin = XMIN, YMIN
    dataframe.extent = frameExtent
# Export to PDF
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, pdfStore)
```

Comment: You have an error in the line setting the `XMIN` variable. `XMIN = extent.YMin`

Comment: I should have noticed that..script now works properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The extent objects need referenced like this:

```
extent = feat.extent
extent.XMin = min(extent.XMin, extent.XMin)
extent.XMax = max(extent.XMax, extent.XMax)
extent.YMin = min(extent.YMin, extent.YMin)
extent.YMax = max(extent.YMax, extent.YMax)
dataframe.extent = extent
```